# Why is it returning the incorrect result for all objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array:

```
arr = [
  { name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
  { name: 'Another', code: '55', number: '004', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
  { name: 'One more', code: 'DAE', number: '003', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
];
```

I'm using the function bellow to create the `id` key:

```
createId(arr){
    this.listWithKey = arr;
    let i = 0;

    this.listWithKey.forEach((item) => {
        Object.defineProperty(item, 'id', {
            get: function () { 
                return i++}, 
                enumerable: true})
});
return this.listWithKey;
}
```

**What I expect:**

```
 this.listWithKey = [
      { id: 0,  name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
      { id: 1, name: 'Another', code: '55', number: '004', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
      { id: 2, name: 'One more', code: 'DAE', number: '003', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}] },
    ];
```

**What is happening:**

```
 this.listWithKey = [
      { id: 6,  name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
      { id: 7, name: 'Another', code: '55', number: '004', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
      { id: 8, name: 'One more', code: 'DAE', number: '003', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
    ];
```

I tried too:

```
createId(arr){
    this.listWithKey = arr;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.listWithKey.length ; i++){
                Object.defineProperty(this.listWithKey[i], 'id', {
            get: function () { 
                return i}, 
                enumerable: true})
};
return this.listWithKey;
}
```

But the result is:

```
this.listWithKey = [
          { id: 3,  name: 'Something', code: 'A33', number: '67', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
          { id: 3, name: 'Another', code: '55', number: '004', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
          { id: 3, name: 'One more', code: 'DAE', number: '003', house:[{"description": "","name": "FD","type": "A"}]},
        ];
```

What should I do to get the correct `id`?

Comment: You're taking the value for the id from a closure. Pass the index argument to [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use that as an id.

Comment: It is referencing value stored in `i` everytime you call the get function, it's not actually setting the property to it's value

Comment: Why not simply `item.id = i++`…?

Comment: As for `6, 7, 8` in the first snippet: it's incrementing `i` every time you read `id`, which probably happens implicitly a few times due to the debugger/console…

Comment: Thanks! I did what @Teemu said !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. What I did:

```
createId(arr){
    this.listWithKey = arr;

    this.listWithKey.forEach((item, index) => {
        Object.defineProperty(item, 'id', {
            get: function () { 
                return index}, 
                enumerable: true})
});
return this.listWithKey;
}
```

Comment: Does the id have to be a getter? It would be less memory-consuming, if you'd do what deceze suggested, i.e. just set a regular property.

Comment: @Teemu I tried it, but i failed...I'm begginer in Javascript...will I use it in the first or in the second function of my question?

Comment: You can use the answer, instead of the getter set `value: index`, that would store a primitive instead of saving `index` variable into closure. Or even simpler: `item.id = index;`. A getter is usually used, when you'd need a calculated value instead of a simple stored value.